# Latest post from each author in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, group-by, distinct

I have a Wordpress site with 28 users and would like to get the latest post from each user (just one post per user). I've tried with a custom sql using both DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but with no success.

This is the closest I have come. It fetches unique posts, but the oldest post instead of the newest.

```
function last_post_per_user() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_results('SELECT ID FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_status=\'publish\' AND post_type=\'post\' AND post_author!=\'1\' GROUP BY post_author');
}

$posts = last_post_per_user();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post_id[] = $post->ID;
}

query_posts( array( 
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post__in'          => $post_id
) );
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

(Have actually tried solving this the whole f*cking day)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
query_posts( array( 
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post__in'          => $post_id
) );
```

with this:

```
query_posts( array( 
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post__in'          => $post_id,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'

) );
```

It will show the newest posts.